# OnCollisionEnter2D is not being called

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm fairly new to Unity and I've decided to work on a simple 2d platformer from youtube tutorials.
Everything works fine until I start using collisions. My problem isn't only that it doesn't work, It's that it doesn't appear at all on auto-complete.
Here is my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class finishLine : MonoBehaviour
{

    void Start()
    {
    
    }


    void Update()
    {
    
    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col) {
        if (col.gameObject.CompareTag("Player")) {
            SceneManager.LoadScene("level2");  
        }
    }
}
```

I've also added rigid bodies and box colliders to both objects (player and finish line).
Anyone know what's wrong?

Comment: Just to be sure you did add rigidbody 2d and the collider 2d and not marked trigger? And this script is on the finish line item?

Comment: Did you add a tag to the object?
to see the objects that collided, add before the condition - `print(col.gameObject.tag);` and `mb print(col.gameObject.name);` for check work

Comment: Make sure that your script is not a child or parent of that object that has a collider2d. It must be on the object itself. Also make sure that you have collider2d instead of a collider. Also check if you have tags on your objects.. also add debug.log in your OnCollisionEnter2d script

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you used BoxCollider2D and not the 3D one.
If the autocomplete doesn't work try restarting VisualStudio or whatever IDE you use. If that doesn't work look in the Unity Settings under External Tools and try regenerating project files. That works for me sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

So a couple things you might want to look into to fix this are:

1. Check if you have the right colliders on both your gameobjects (in this exmaple box collider 2D I assume)
2. Check if either of your colliders has the "Is Trigger" box check or not. If yes then uncheck it
3. Make sure your player gameobject has the "Player" tag and the same as the tag you compare in your script because compare tag is case sentitive
4. Check if you have your **finishLine** script on the object you want as the root object meaning it's the parent of all the other one inside it and has no parent (this doesn't need to be the case all the time but in this scenario it might help fix the problem)

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the trigger box in the colliders?
Does any one of those objects have a rigid body?
Did you have other functions that destroyed the character when it reaches the destination that is meant to be the trigger?
You can try to set up a two new cubes for testing purposes to narrow down the problem.